# Why does Python's map() function swap values position in each return?

Tags: python

im studying python and trying to learn how to use the map() function.

Had the idea to change letters from a string for equivalent+1 in alphabet, ex.: abc -> bcd

wrote the following code:

```
m = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


def func(s):
    return m[m.index(s) + 1]

l = "abc"

print(set(map(func, l)))
```

But every excecution returns a different order for the letters

I got the expected answer by using:

```
l2 = [func(i) for i in s]
print(l2)
```

But i wanted to understand the map() function and how it works. Tried to read the documentation but I could not understand much.
Sorry about my bad english and my lack of experience in python :/

Answer (score 5):

It is because you are converting to `set` in `set(map(func, l))` and `set` is an unordered collection in Python.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects....Being an unordered collection, sets do not record element position or order of insertion. Accordingly, sets do not support indexing, slicing, or other sequence-like behavior.

If you replace `print(set(map(func, l)))` with `print(list(map(func, l)))`, you'll not see this behavior.

Comment: Thanks bro, that's what happens when u paste a code from google without understend it